# Is there a way to use MLP/any other Algorithms which take the objective and error functions as input and returns the optimum parameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, mlp

I was thinking if there is a pre-built implementation of MLP in python that can take my objective function, loss function, and tolerance as input and return the optimum parameters for my function. I have gone through the MLPs in Tensorflow and scikit-learn but there seems to be nothing of this sort. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your objective function is differentiable this is literally what a neural network is designed to do. You can write any function in TF as an objective, and then train your MLP with say SGD. It is a matter of understanding how things work or accepting that "pre built" is not going to be as easy as a function called "solve my problem", it requires a few more commands, but in the end what you are asking for is literally any NN implementation, let it be TF, Keras etc.

For example you can use [Keras](https://keras.io/api/losses/) and implement your custom loss

```
def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)  # Note the `axis=-1`

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_loss_fn)
```